# Displaying content at the right of the page as block in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I display contents of the `right-info` div vertically ,at the right end of my page in bootstrap 4?

I've tried these:

```html
<div class="row right-info flex-column justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-md-4  company-info-area">Col-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Col-2 Below Col-1</div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="row  flex-column flex-row-reverse right-info">
    <div class="col-md-4  company-info-area">Col-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Col-2 Below Col-1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float:right`.

```css
.right-info {
float:right;
}

.col-md-4 {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row right-info flex-column justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-md-4  company-info-area">Col-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Col-2 Below Col-1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align:right` just makes the text appear on the right of the div . I want the whole div to be displayed at the right of my screen

Comment: Nevermind. It did. I accidently removed the right-info class. Thanks!